# SNS notification of failed EMR job

Tags: amazon-web-services, emr

Is there a way to configure AWS, EMR, and SNS such that a message is published to an SNS topic when an EMR job fails? I am using a transient EMR cluster for a nightly ETL, and need to be notified if the process fails for any reason.

Answer (score 3):

I needed the same functionality and what I did is I use the AWS data pipeline to create the cluster and send the SNS notification if the pipeline fails.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-emractivity.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-snsalarm.html